# Property change is not propagated to binding target (UWP)

Tags: xaml, binding, uwp, inotifypropertychanged

I have a ViewModel and a Class. They look like this:

```
//viewmodel
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    private MyClass myClass;
    public MyClass MyClass{
        get{
            return myClass;
        }
        set{
            this.myClass = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string testString;
    public string TestString{
                get{
            return testString;
        }
        set{
            this.testString = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel(){
        this.MyClass = new MyClass();
        this.TestString = "blah, blah, blah"
    }}



//class
    public class MyClass : ViewModelBase{
    private string  myString;
    public string MyString{
        get {
        return myString
        }
        set{
            this.myString = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MyClass (){
        this.MyString = "25";   }}
```

The base class - ViewModelBase implements INotifyChange and contains OnPropertyChanged handler logic. 
I have a UserControl where I wish to bind values from MyClass like this:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind  Path=MyViewModel.MyClass.MyString, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
```

However this does not work. Value is binded in initialisation correctly, but any change in MyViewModel.MyClass.MyString is not reflected in texblock, the text remains the same. The OnPropertyChange is raised, the breakpoint in ViewModelBase is hit with MyString value changed, but it is somehow not propagated to texblock.
Binding on simple value from MyClass works like charm, this textblock is updated, when property is changed:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind  Path=MyViewModel.TestString, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
```

What am I missing? Why the textblock with binding to "MyViewModel.MyClass.MyString" is not being updated?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code you provided and don't think there is any problem with it. Where the problem could be, however, is your Page's code-behind. By any chance, aren't you using this as the property declaration?

```
public MyViewModel MyViewModel => new MyViewModel();
```

Because in this case, every access to `MyViewModel` property evaluates as a new instance of `MyViewModel` class. In this configuration, you would properly change the property, but the UI would never notice, as you would update the property on a new instance. If you instead use

```
public MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; } = new MyViewModel();
```

You will get the correct behavior of creating only one instance when the page is created.

I have the following code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; } = new MyViewModel();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyViewModel.MyClass.MyString = "test";
    }
}
```

And my simple `ViewModelBase`:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not setting MyViewModel  through lambda operator, however I am resolving it from DI container like this „“this. MyViewModel = DIManager.Instance.DIContainer.Resolve<MyViewModel>();“. MyViewModel is registered in DI as singleton, so I assuming that it is nothing wrong with the instance. Also the MyViewModel.TestString is working well. The problem is just with properties in MyViewModel.MyClass .

Comment: By the way my ViewModelBase is same as yours, I am just running it within dispatcher, since it was problem with updating UI from background threat. I don’t assume that it is a problem, since as I said MyViewModel.TestString works. If you have any idea it will be very appreciated.

Comment: That is very weird, really. What happens when you completely replace the `MyClass` with a new instance? LIke `MyViewModel.MyClass = new MyClass() { MyString = "something else" }`

Comment: I have tried it, unfortunately the behavior is exactly the same. I have already found workaround, but I am not particularly happy with it. In UserControl I create a new string property "newString". I subscribe to event MyViewModel.MyClass.PropertyChanged and in the handler I have "this.newString = this.MyViewModel.MyClass.MyString" and in xaml I am binding to "newString". This actually works, but it is not very neat and clean solution. Hopefully it will be just temporary.

Comment: This is very weird, I have the exact same code on my PC and it does work. By any chance, could you create a new solution, create the same code there and send it to me or share to GitHub?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. That code is just simplification of part of quite big project I am working on and I am not allowed to share it. There are also interfaces involved and I didn't use them in that sample. If I will be desperate enough (not very far from that right now, anyway), I will try to find some time, to make more adequate "dummy" copy of that problem and try to post is somewhere. Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes any smaller scale example would be appreciated. As I said, I think I have exact copy of what you shared and it works as expected...